# Should I write an inner function for a generator expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I frequently find I would prefer to write a generator expression (rather than creating an empty list and appending to it, for example). However, this means I need to put the expression into a function to call it.

It feels messy to write a hanging function or method somewhere else when it is only used in one section of code.

For shorter generators I would just write a one line generator expression or list comprehension which is clean, no problem.

As a toy example:

```
def gen_test():
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(20):
            yield i * j

def main():
    return sum(gen_test())
```

If `main()` is actually a method inside a class, extracting `gen_test()` out to another function or method adds unnecessary clutter, so I'm tempted by:

```
def main():

    def gen_test():
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(20):
                yield i * j

    return sum(gen_test())
```

This is faster than appending to a list:

```
def main():

    vals = []
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(20):
            vals.append(i * j)

    return sum(vals)
```

It seems fine when there's just the one inner function, but often I write a few of these ~4-6 line generator expressions for a function; should I still be writing an inner function for each one?

Comment: Moving code into small functions is a good practice, because it usually improves readability. However, the functions should be named properly: `gen_test` should be named something like `yield_multiples` and should have arguments instead of magic constants (10 and 20). Then it probably makes sense not to make them an inner function, because you cannot write unit tests for inner functions.

Comment: @pschill I hadn't considered the issue of unit testing the inner functions but that makes sense, thanks.

Comment: I'm not saying there aren't expressions complex enough that warrant their own functions, but also keep in mind that simple examples like that one you used can be easily written in a line. The itertools module may also come handy.

Comment: @Reti43 Yeah, these toy examples are a bit short and could easily be one-liners as I said; I didn't want to add long examples as I think it just confuses the issue. I'm more concerned with when I'm writing two or more somewhat long generator expressions in a single method.